# Edit content of a field from another Visualforce page on Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, lookup, visualforce

I am trying to create a custom lookup page on Salesforce: from a first Visualforce page, I open a second one in which there are a series of available choices; then I click on one of those choices and then I expect the latter page (the custom lookup) to close and the value of my choice to appear in the first page's lookup field.

I am unsure on this very last point: how do I make my choice appear in the earlier page?

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this awesome Jeff Douglas post](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/) you need to call function lookupPick2 in following manner

```
top.window.opener.lookupPick2('{!FormTag}','{!TextBox}_lkid','{!TextBox}','{!a.Id}','{!a.Name}', false);
```

Please read the entire post to get the full picture.

Answer (score 0):

Where is LookupPick2 documented?  When I google for it all I find is code examples and blog posts.  Is there any documentation for it?  I'll keep looking, but wherever it may be doesn't rank very high...